# Group and represent pie chart

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
Hours  Person

10     Jack
20     Louis
10     Jack
30     Anne
10     Anne
```

And I want to represent this data as a pie chart where 50% of the hours belongs to Anne, 25% to Jack an 25% to Louis. I have tried with goupby but it doesn´t represent what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby('Person')['Hours'].sum().plot.pie(autopct='%.2f')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works perfect, I missed the ['Hours'] , for that reason groupby didn't work.